# How do you turn on Adiantum on Linux 5.0?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, encryption, google

I read recently that Linux 5.0 introduced support for Adiantum, Google's low-power encryption standard, and I felt like playing around with it. But, I can't find anything on the Internet about it, so how can I turn it on? Or is it not designed for PCs?

Comment: https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_5.0#Adiantum_file_system_encryption_for_low_power_devices

Answer (score 1):

It's called Adiantum and the option is called CONFIG_CRYPTO_ADIANTUM.